# SQL command for multiple "AND" & "OR" operation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am going to write a sql command to retreive data by choosing multiple `or` selection. I have given written query by me, does anyone have alternative `sql` query for my query which gives same result?

It gives `startdate` for userid `4` and userid `37` in between given date range.

```
SELECT 
   UserID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM   
   dbo.TimeEntry
WHERE  
   (UserID = 4) AND (StartDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-02-02 00:00:00',    
102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-02-05 00:00:00', 102)) OR
(UserID = 37) AND (StartDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-02-02 00:00:00', 102)
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-02-05 00:00:00', 102))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, StartDate, EndDate 
    FROM dbo.TimeEntry 
    WHERE UserID IN (4,37) 
        AND StartDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-02-02 00:00:00', 102)
                          AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-02-05 00:00:00', 102)
```